# Prevent clicks until AJAX promise is complete

Tags: jquery

How can I prevent additional clicks on an element until the promise from the ajax is complete?

The element itself is not a button

I want to prevent clicks on `.my_button`:

```
$(document).on('click', '.my_button', function () {
    $.ajax({

    })
        .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            

        })
        .fail(function () {
            
        })
        .always(function () {
            // enable clicks again
        })
});
```

Is it possible with bind/unbind? If so I wasn't able to find the correct syntax

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention this important part: This is not a button element

Comment: Similar to all the other suggestions (and existing SO questions/answers) - add a class with `pointer-events:none` then remove the class when done.

Answer (score 0):

You can create variable with active state of your button and toggle it like this:

```js
let isButtonEnabled = true;

$(document).on('click', '.my_button', function () {
    if (!isButtonEnabled) return;

    isButtonEnabled = false;

    $.ajax({

    })
        .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            

        })
        .fail(function () {
            
        })
        .always(function () {
            // enable clicks again
            isButtonEnabled = true;
        })
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post becuase I forgot to mention that this is not a button element

Comment: @Stackerito ok, then use variable instead, I've updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Disable the button, then enable it in the callback function.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#my_button', function() {
  let button = this;
  button.disabled = true;
  $.ajax({
    })
    .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    })
    .fail(function() {
    })
    .complete(function() {
      button.disabled = false;
    })
});
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention this important part: This is not a button element - edited the post now

Comment: Please post a [mre] including the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a flag to track whether the operation is in progress or not.  For example:

```
let isFetching = false;

$(document).on('click', '#my_button', function () {

  // return early if already running
  if (isFetching) {
    return;
  }    

  // update the value
  isFetching = true;
  $.ajax({

  })
  .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        
  })
  .fail(function () {
        
  })
  .complete(function () {
    // reset the value
    isFetching = false;
  })
});
```

Basically, rather than trying to prevent the click itself or complicate things with unbinding/re-binding, simply don't execute the operation if you're tracking that it's currently in progress.